# Condition in Template Definition

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, partial-specialization

I want to change the return type of a template function depending on a property of the given type. Is there a possibility to do something like this, maybe with partial specialization (one for the cool T and one for not cool ones)?

```
template<typename T, typename ret = T::IsCool ? int : float>
inline ret get() {}
```

(It is always guaranteed, that T has the `bool` property `IsCool`.)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Comment: @nwp You do know that you're supposed to put answers in the answer box below, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I was under the impression that link-only answers are not answers, but feel free to add some text and make it one.

Comment: @nwp Yes, but explaining it a bit and providing an example makes a good answer :)

Comment: Do note that if you want to change the return based on whether `IsCool` returns true or false then it needs to be `constexpr`.

Comment: In my real project it defines if `T` is allowed to appear multiple times. Therefore I want to decide to return just a `T*` or a `std::vector<T*>&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `std::conditional` to achieve this.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

You can use it like so:

C++11

```
template<typename T, typename ret = std::conditional<T::IsCool, int, float>::type>
inline ret get() {}
```

C++14

```
template<typename T, typename ret = std::conditional_t<T::IsCool, int, float>>
inline ret get() {}
```